# DryIoc, LightInject experiences

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, light-inject

I would like to use some .NET IoC container with good performance results. I read [this article](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) about IoC containers performance and DryIoc and LightInject seem to be the best. But I did not find some reviews of them especially some experiences from the real using.

- Do you have some experiences with DryIoc and LightInject?
- What IoC container would you recommend for the performance sensitive project?

Comment: I suspect this question to be subjective and not a very good fit for Stackoverflow. But do note though that for most applications the performance of your DI library is not an issue (the bottleneck is usually in I/O). I'm the creator of [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) and Simple Injector is in the top 4 of fastest containers in the article you linked to. So I think you can take my word for it. And even if performance is important, there are many more criteria to choose from when selecting your DI library.

Comment: I'm aware of this is maybe subjective question, but I'm asking for a concrete experience not a feeling, so that's the reason why I risked to ask:) Thank you for your proposal, your IoC container looks nice and simple to use. I will look at it.

Comment: Some definition of "performance sensitive project" is likely needed. All projects want "to go fast" most projects don't have true performance concerns outside of IO.

Comment: Before making concrete suggestions and adhering to a specific IoC container please make a try outs with following and make a decision that potentially suits your needs
[StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/)
[Spring.Net](http://springframework.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use LightInject in middle-size project and I was very satisfied with all features, documentation and support. I recommend to use LightInject.

Comment: I am interested in this topic for similar reasons as I am considering replacing a current "poor man's" implementation of DI with an IoC container in a real-time trading application. Obviously in such a context performance is absolutely critical. I too was looking at DryIoc and LightInject. Any further details of your experiences would be beneficial. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. And which IoC container did you choose? I didn't do some performance tests of LightInject but I used it in middle size project and it works without any problems. It was mainly CRUD application and read/write actions took most of time. Maybe this is reason why I didn't see performance problem. I think replace of the IoC container is not big deal, try to replace your current IoC for Lightinject and you will see. Write me please info then.

Answer (score 0):

LightInject doesn't resolve concrete classes that was not registered within container.
You can provide fallback method (RegisterFallback), but resolving dependency in it using same container causes StackOverflowException.